# I have a Document in mongodb where total_units need to updated by the sum of units present in sub document

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

```json
  {
    product: "mobile",
    total_units: 10,
    list: [
      {
        "brand": "samsung",
        "units": 5
      },
      {
        "brand": "apple",
        "units": 5
      }
    ]
  }
```

I need to update `total_units` based on the `units` present in the array of sub-documents

I figured out how to update get the `total_sum` but not how to update the total_sum in the document

```js
db.example3.aggregate({$project: { "result":{$sum: "$list.units"}}})
```

but how to update in the document

```js
db.example3.update({},{"$set":{"total_units":{"$sum":"$list.units"}}})
```

the excepted result should be if the brand:apple has the units of 7 and brand samsung has value of 5 the the total units section should be total_units:12

Comment: You could use a pipeline in the `update`.

Comment: needed expected results

Comment: Hi @Naveen I have added the excepted results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo@mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TgjZUC-jlG_)
Add aggregation pipeline to your query. In your case you missed brackets
https://mongoplayground.net/p/TgjZUC-jlG_

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "SizeOfList": {
        $size: "$list"
      },
      "total_units": {
        $sum: "$list.units"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

`output`

```
//outputs
[
  {
    "SizeOfList": 2,
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "list": [
      {
        "brand": "samsung",
        "units": 5
      },
      {
        "brand": "apple",
        "units": 5
      }
    ],
    "product": "mobile",
    "total_units": 10
  }
]
```